# MongoDB-Java: How to make $geoNear to first do query, then distance?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to query and sort documents as followed:

- Query only for documents older than SOMETIME.
- Within range of AROUNDME_RANGE_RADIUS_IN_RADIANS.
- Get distance for each document.
- Sort them by time. New to Old.
- Overall it should return up to 20 results.

But it seems that since $geoNear is by default limited to 100 results, I get unexpected results.

I see $geoNear working in the following order:

1. Gets docs from the entire collection, by distance.
2. And only then executes the given Query.

Is there a way to reverse the order? 

MongoDB v2.6.5

Java Driver v2.10.1

Thank you.

Example document in my collection:

```
{
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-12-27T06:52:17.949Z"),
    "text" : "hello",
    "loc" : [ 
        34.76701564815013, 
        32.05852053407342
    ]
}
```

I'm using aggregate since from what I understood it's the only way to sort by "timestamp" and get the distance.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("timestamp", new BasicDBObject("$lt", SOMETIME));

            // aggregate: geoNear
            double[] currentLoc = new double[] {
                    Double.parseDouble(myLon), 
                    Double.parseDouble(myLat)
            };
            DBObject geoNearFields = new BasicDBObject();
            geoNearFields.put("near", currentLoc);
            geoNearFields.put("distanceField", "dis");
            geoNearFields.put("maxDistance", AROUNDME_RANGE_RADIUS_IN_RADIANS));
            geoNearFields.put("query", query);
            //geoNearFields.put("num", 5000);  // FIXME: a temp solution I would really like to avoid
            DBObject geoNear = new BasicDBObject("$geoNear", geoNearFields);

            // aggregate: sort by timestamp
            DBObject sortFields = new BasicDBObject("timestamp", -1);
            DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", sortFields);

            // aggregate: limit
            DBObject limit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", 20);

            AggregationOutput output = col.aggregate(geoNear, sort, limit);
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Yes `$geoNear` should be the first stage in the pipeline. Completely missed that point. Is the inclusion of - `geoNearFields.put("num",20)`, giving you the correct results?

Comment: No, `num` has to be the size of the entire collection. That's why the code has a commented out num=5000

Comment: The `num` key marks the maximum number of documents to return, it acts exactly as the `limit` stage.

Comment: Yes, but the $geoNear limit/num is executed before the query. The query is done on a small group of documents, instead of the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `$match` stage at the top of the pipleine, to filter the documents before the `$geonear` stage.

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("timestamp", 
                                        new BasicDBObject("$lt", SOMETIME));
AggregationOutput output = col.aggregate(match,geoNear, sort, limit);
```

The below piece of code now, is not required,

```
geoNearFields.put("query", query);
```

Comment: Is it better than to do: `geoNearFields.put("num", db.getCollection(COL_NAME).getCount((BasicDBObject)query.copy()));` ?

Comment: Yes. The `$match` stage filters out the records that we don't want **before** the `$geoNear` stage kicks in. It always fares better than applying the `$geoNear` stage to all the documents and then returning only the relevant documents.

Comment: `geoNearFields.put("num",..)` is not required when you use the `limit` option.

Comment: Sorry, but the it doesn't work. I get an exception from mongo: `"exception: $geoNear is only allowed as the first pipeline stage"`